# How to use RVM in CSH environment?

Tags: rvm, tcsh

I have installed RVM using following procedure (https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

1. `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --rails` - it has installed RVM (single-user) in $HOME. (Question: How do I specify a non-default RVM installation path in above command?)
2. Updated $PATH in my ~/.cshrc to have RVM bin path as below. `set path = ($HOME/.rvm/bin ${path})`

   ```
   prompt>which rvm 
   $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm 
   prompt>rvm -v
    rvm 1.26.9 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
   prompt>rvm list
    rvm rubies
    # No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.
   ```
3. Though I have used --ruby and --rails in step (1), I noticed that Ruby & Rails were not installed as part of (1). So trying to install Ruby myself, using `rvm install ruby`
4. Per RVM installation instruction, I need to `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`, which uses bash to execute. But our entire environment has tcsh as shell, and I cannot afford to change it.

   ```
    prompt>source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
    if: Too few arguments.
   ```

   It is erroring out since our default shell is TCSH and the script is written in BASH.

   ```
    prompt> echo $SHELL
     /bin/tcsh
   ```

   And we use ~/.cshrc to configure our environment.

Can someone help me to fix the setup, so that I can use RVM?

Thanks in advance.

I tried following options:

1. Using this as workaround now: [How do I use RVM with tcsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380203/how-do-i-use-rvm-with-tcsh) (it doesn't work good when I try running `rvm use` to switch Ruby Version.
       prompt>rvm use 1.8.6-p383

   ```
   RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

   You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
   Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
   Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.
   ```
2. http://po-ru.com/diary/using-rvm-with-tcsh/ does not help
3. [RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963018/rvm-is-not-a-function-selecting-rubies-with-rvm-use-will-not-work) is not a solution for my problem. I verified it is not working.

Unfortunately, we are not using ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc environments? Does it mean RVM is not supporting CSH/TCSH environments?

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: *"Using this as workaround now: How do I use RVM with tcsh?"*, no, as I pointed out in that answer, you're supposed to set `$ruby_version` like so: `set ruby_version = 1.8.6-p383`, after reloading your tcshrc, all your environment variables should be updated. This *effectively* does the same as `rvm use`, but it was easier to implement (I had other stuff to do, and I don't use rvm that often...)

Comment: If you want to do it properly, so that `rvm use` works, by the way, then look at how `./scripts/extras/rvm.fish` (for the fish shell) does it, and translate that to tcsh.

Comment: Linking to my answer here, in case it helps:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380203/how-do-i-use-rvm-with-tcsh/28653516#28653516